# Count Even Numbers User has Inputted PYTHON 3

Tags: python, count

I must create two functions. One that can tell whether one number is odd or even by returning t/f, and the other will call the first function then return how many even numbers there are.

This is my code so far:

```
    Even = [0,2,4,6,8]
    IsEvenInput = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

    def IsEvenDigit(a):
        if a in Even:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    y = IsEvenDigit(IsEvenInput)
    print(y)


    def CountEven(b):
        count = 0
        for a in b:
            if IsEvenDigit(a):
                count+=1
        return count
    d = input("Please enter more than one number: ")
    y = CountEven(d)
    print(y)
```

This keeps outputting 0 and doesn't actually count. What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: I realise you're a beginner, but it's the perfect time to read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the python coding style guide.

Comment: Why is this tagged recursion?

Comment: @Junuxx just numbers 0-9

Comment: Do you actually need to create 2 functions?

Comment: @Xaranke yup that's what I'll be asked to do in the exam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach:

```
def is_even(number):
    return number % 2 == 0

def even_count(numbers_list):
    count = 0

    for number in numbers_list:
        if is_even(number): count += 1

    return count

raw_numbers = input("Please enter more than one number: ")
numbers_list = [int(i) for i in raw_numbers.split()]

count = even_count(numbers_list)
print(count)
```

This will take care of all other numbers too.

Comment: How about just `def is_even(number): return not (number & 1)`

Comment: I'd stay away because (2 & 1) is 0 while not (2 & 1) is True. **Very** counterintuitive.

Comment: Well, 2&1 is supposed be 0 since its a bit wise and.  Any even number will end up with a 0 in the rightmost spot, so n&1 will be zero.  To negate that and make it Boolean, not is used

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee: Do you not think it inappropriate to be playing code-golf with a beginner's question?

Comment: Especially as `lambda n:n%2==0` is shorter than `lambda n:not(n&1)`!

Comment: It's a common construct using the lsb. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382403/how-to-judge-a-int-number-odd-or-even-the-binary-way

Comment: @user2387370 if you want to golf, I think `lambda x:~x&1` is shorter.

Comment: @MattH is exactly what I was thinking

Answer (score 1):

```
d = input("Please enter more than one number: ")
```

This is going to return a string of numbers, perhaps separated by spaces. You'll need to `split()` the string into the sequence of text digits and then turn those into integers.

---

There's a general approach to determining whether a number is odd or even using the modulus / remainder operator, `%`: if the remainder after division by `2` is `0` then the number is even.

Answer (score 0):

You are counting whether the integers - [0, 2, 4, 6, 8] etc. - are characters in a string - "0", "2", "4", "6", "8" etc. Currently, IsEvenDigit(a) will never be true, because a character in a string will not be in the list of even integers, so the code beneath the if statement will never be executed. You need `IsEvenDigit(int(a))` in the CountEven function.

On another topic, a commenter to your post suggested reading PEP 8. Your code is actually formatted pretty well, its just in Python, CamelCase is used just for classes, and words_seperated_by_underscores is used for variables and function names.

Or if you want brevity and unreadability, some code:

```
main = lambda: sum(map(lambda x: int(x) % 2 == 0, (i for i in input("Enter a number: "))))
main()
```

It does define 2 (anonymous) functions!

Comment: Then I come back with this error File "C:\Python31\python3\practicedouble", line 16, in CountEven
    for a in b:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Where did you put the `int`? Edit the code in your question so it's updated.

Comment: Line 16 and in variable 'd'

Comment: No, you want `IsEvenDigit(int(a))`, as I said in my post. You can't turn the whole string into an integer, because then you can't iterate through the individual digits.

Answer (score 0):

So by calling CountEvent(d) outside the scope of the function CountEven, you aren't using recursion, you're simple calling the function after it's been defined.

Try reducing the amount of code outside of your functions.

```
    #Start by declaring your functions:
    def isEven(n):
        return n % 2 == 0

    def countEven():
        count = 0
        string_of_numbers = input("Please enter numbers separated by spaces: ")
        list_of_number_characters = string_of_numbers.split(' ')
        for number in list_of_number_characters:
            number_as_int = int(number)
            if isEven(number_as_int) == True:
                count = count + 1
        print("There were " + str(count) + " even numbers found.")


    countEven() #Call the function that runs your program
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
def is_even(n):
    return not n % 2

def count_even(numbers)
    return sum(map(is_even, numbers))

nums = input("Enter numbers separated by spaces: ")
nums = map(int, nums.split())
print(count_even(nums))
```